# Is it possible to $.post inside a $.get in jquery (Flask + Python)

Tags: python, jquery, flask

I'm relatively new to Flask in Python. So please bear with me if my question sounds stupid.

I've a `GET` function like this below:

```
@app.route('/transactions', methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_transactions():
    ...
```

I've a text box (#transaction_year) on html and I'd need that input to be used within this above function (as a $.post). The above function is called by following JQuery

```
$('#get-transactions-btn').on('click', function (e) {
        $.get('/transactions', function (data) {
          ....
});
});
```

The problem is when the button (get-transactions-btn) is clicked, the function (get_transactions) runs as a `GET` and fetches data. Is it possible to do something like below to run $.post before $.get is executed and still have the value from the input text box (#transaction_year)?

```
$('#get-transactions-btn').on('click', function (e) {
        $.get('/transactions', function (data) {
          var transaction_year = $("#transaction_year").val();
          $.post("/transactions", { transaction_year: transaction_year })
          ....
});
});
```

So that I can use it within my function like below?

```
@app.route('/transactions', methods=['GET','POST'])
def get_transactions():
    # Store the value from post here
    transaction_year = float(request.form['transaction_year'])
    ...
```

Thank you and appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get a workaround for this. I created a separate function to store the $.post value in a global variable input_year.

```
input_year = 1
@app.route('/transactions_input', methods=['POST'])
def get_transactions_input():
    global input_year
    transaction_year = float(request.form['transaction_year'])

    input_year = transaction_year

    return 'Done'
```

Updated JQuery to below:

```
 $('#get-transactions-btn').on('click', function (e) {
        var transaction_year = $("#transaction_year").val();
        $.post("/transactions_input", { transaction_year: transaction_year }) 
        $.get('/transactions', function (data) {
        ....
});
});
```

Global variable sets the input box value and this can be used inside `/transactions`.